# Measures on views create on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

After redesigning an app we got larger load times on new views create (the old version had almost no images and was much faster). We use ViewFlipper to navigate through the views. The first two views, which are created, are two layouts with ListViews, whose elements have background images and other graphics. Coincidentally we found, that each time, when a new View is created and is put on the view stack, the app calculates the dimensions of each existing view (Among other calls the getView() method of the ListView adapters several times). The trace log of each call looks like:

> LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1369 LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 660   LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 553 LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12937 TabHost(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 5045 TabHost(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 293  TabHost(View).measure(int, int) line: 12937 RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(View, RelativeLayout$LayoutParams, int, int) line: 594 RelativeLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 376   RelativeLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12937  FrameLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 5045 FrameLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 293   FrameLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12937 LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 5045 LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1369 LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 660   LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 553 LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12937 PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 5045 PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 293 PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 2180     PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).measure(int, int) line: 12937

and so on...
I think it is the reason why the app has become so slow.
What can I do to prevent the app to do these measures or to make the app faster?

ListAdapter getView():

```
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row;
    Entry entry = null;
    if (objects.get(pos) instanceof Entry) {
        entry = (Entry) objects.get(pos) ;

        Boolean isGroupedEntry;
        if (entry.getGroup() != null && entry.isGroupedEntry()) {
            isGroupedEntry = true;
        } else {
            isGroupedEntry = false;
        }

        if (convertView != null) {
            row = convertView;
        } else {
            row = new EntryBoxFrameLayout(getContext());
        }

        ((EntryBoxFrameLayout) row).configureFor(entry);

    } else {
        row = new View(ContentManager.getInstance().getContext());
    }

    row.setSelected(false);
    row.setTag(pos);
    return row;
}
```

in configureFor() i set some texts and then:

```
        if (entry.getUserIsSignedUp() > 0) {
        this.setBackgroundColor("4A4A4A");
        this.findViewById(R.id.star).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.findViewById(R.id.entry_face).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entry_face_loggedin);
        fulldate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    } else {
        this.setBackgroundColor(entry.getColorHex());
        this.findViewById(R.id.star).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        this.findViewById(R.id.entry_face).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entry_face);
        fulldate.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    if (entry.getGroup() != null) {
        this.findViewById(R.id.imgGroupArrow).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (entry.isGroupExpanded()) {
            ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imgGroupArrow)).setImageResource(R.drawable.entry_up_arrow);
        } else {
            ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imgGroupArrow)).setImageResource(R.drawable.entry_down_arrow);
        }
        this.setGroupContainer(true);
    } else {
        this.findViewById(R.id.imgGroupArrow).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        this.setGroupContainer(false);
    }

    String filename = entry.getCacheFilename();
    Drawable entryimage = null;
    if (filename != null) {
        try {
            FileInputStream input = ContentManager.getInstance().getContext().openFileInput(filename);
            entryimage = new BitmapDrawable(ContentManager.getInstance().getContext().getResources(), input);
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    if (entryimage != null) {
        this.getImageView().setImageDrawable(entryimage);
    } else {
        this.getImageView().setImageResource(R.drawable.entry_placeholder);
    }
```

Comment: the getView() is the one that is slowing your app down. The listview recycles view objects when scrolling through the list. Are you downloading the images? are the images in your resources?

Comment: Each element of a ListView has some images from the resources and one downloaded image.
I don't understand why the app calls getView() method even if the ListView is not on the top of the stack and do it several times for each element.

Comment: Thats how the listview works.. if you optimize the getView() method your slowing down will dissapear. post some code of you getView() method. here are already some pointers: for the images from resources: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html and for the images downloaded: make use of lazy loading e.g. http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/

Comment: Here are also two google io sessions regarding optimization of listview, (a must watch for every android developer): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: @user1281750 i added some code to my question. But is it really ok, that the listview's getView() is called each time a new view is created somewhere in the app?

thanks for the links, i will take a look on it.

Comment: Its really ok, only if you optimize the getView() method, in your getView method you should use a convertView and viewHolder to get it smooth. also don't load the images in the getView method, use a reference.

Comment: Ok. I will watch the videos and try to change the class. Please write an answer - so i can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I have bundled the comments into an answer ;) Good luck coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getView() method is slowing your application down. The listView recycles view objects for performance.

There are many learning resources covering this.

From google I/O conference and from creator of listView: Romain Guy

- [Make your Android UI Fast and Efficient](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA)
- [The world of listview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Optimisation regarding images

- Downloaded from the internet: [LazyLoading](http://www.google.com/search?q=lazyloading%20android)
- From your resources: [displaying bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

For more code examples:

- Google for optimization listview
- Google for lazy loading listview
- Google for convertview, viewholder listview